# How can I return json data when Laravel 5 catch exception?

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-5

How can I return json data when laravel catch exception?
I'd like to return Json data when the data does not exist on database.

When laravel found the record from database, it returns correct json data.Yeah!
If laravel have fail to search any record, it doesn't give json data!
laravel just redireted the page which shows "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." and give soem extra information, "ModelNotFoundException".

Following code is what I tried.

```
    public function show($id)
    {
            try {
                    $statusCode = 200;
                    $response = [
                            'todo' => []
                    ];

                    $todo = Todo::findOrFail($id);

                    $response['todo']= [
                            'id'       =>       $todo->id,
                            'title'    =>       $todo->title,
                            'body'     =>       $todo->body,
                    ]; 

            } catch(Exception $e) {
                    // I think laravel doesn't go through following exception
                    $statusCode = 404;   
                    $response = [
                            "error" => "You do not have that record"
                    ];

            } finally {
                    return response($response, $statusCode);

            }
   }
```

Comment: Try to catch exception like this: `catch(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e)`

Comment: I tried, but it didn't catch anything. So I changed it to if  condition. I know it's not perfect, but at least it return json...I will try the idea you given. There might be some exception class...I guess....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem.. First, I changed findOrFail method to find method. Second, I realized Exception and Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e couldn't catch anything. So I changed to if condition. Then it works.

```
    public function show($id)
    {        
            $statusCode = 200;
            $response = [
                    'todo' => []
            ];

            $todo = Todo::find($id);

            if ( is_null($todo) ) {
                    $statusCode = 404;
                    $response = [
                            "error" => "The record doesn't exist"
                    ];

            } else {
                    $response['todo']= [
                            'id'       =>       $todo->id,
                            'title'    =>       $todo->title,
                            'body'     =>       $todo->body,
                    ]; 

            }

            return response($response, $statusCode);
    }
```

Comment: "if ( is_null($todo) ) {" i would write it as "if (!$todo instanceOf Todo ) {" for more accuracy :)